# How can I remove time from a mvc datepicker and set a default value in a razor view?

Tags: c#, html, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my datepicker:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthdate, "{dd MM yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = DateTime.Now } })
```

It currently displays the date like this: `01-01-0001 00:00`

Also the default time is wrong. I want it to be DateTime.Now as the default.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `type="datetime-local"`:

```
<input type="datetime-local" asp-for="Birthdate" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("s")" />
```